# Save chatID and text sent to a telegram bot, in a database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, telegram-bot

I'm developing a springboot application where i register the bot via token and username, and i just write some code in the class extending the `TelegramLongPollingBot`

```
@Autowired
BotService botService;
        .
        .
        .
if (certain Condition is met )) {
//send the text i retrieved from the bot api which is called command and access the service class and use it to create a ticket
    botService.createTicket(command);
```

But what i'm always getting is:
`Cannot invoke "BotService.createTicket(String)" because "this.BotService is null"`
Not only a service class, anything i try to access from this class gives me a `NullPointerException`

A small note everything is working fine it's just i can't send the messages i receive from the bot api to my service class or any other thing called from inside this class.

I need to know how to call a class without getting a null pointer, and hence save my needed info in the database.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was from the dependency where instead of getting the `spring-boot-telegram` dependency i got the normal `org.telegram` dependency.